# How my program know if the CPU is SMP or Single core

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I hope my thread in Linux uses `spin_lock()` if the CPU is SMP or use `mutex()` if it is single core in source code level for compatibility.

How my source code identify if it is single core or SMP?

Thank you for your advice.

Daum

Comment: Are you talking about kernel programming or user space one?

Comment: @AndyShevchenko op wants to know how runtime determines whether underlying architecture is single core or SMP. His assumption is that mutex runs for former while spin_lock for latter on the fly

Comment: First,  I'm concerning kernel programming.

Comment: But I'm also want to know if I should use pthread_spin_lock() or pthread_mutex() according to the CPU numbers (i.e. SP or SMP).

Answer (score 0):

In cpumask.h, there is a macro defined num_online_cpus which check the cpu_online_mask variable to find the number of cpus up.